# Transitive closure of a relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Having trouble answering the question.

Let $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $\mathcal{R}$ the relation on $A$ with matrix representation:

$$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
&1&2&3&4&5\\
\hline
1&T&F&F&F&F\\
2&F&T&F&T&F\\
3&F&F&T&F&F\\
4&F&T&F&T&T\\
5&F&F&F&T&T\end{array}$$

**(i):** Determine the transitive closure $\mathcal{R}^*$ of $\mathcal{R}$.  Express your answer as a set of ordered pairs.

**(ii):** Write down the partition of the set $A$ into equivalence classes induced by $\mathcal{R}^*$.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  In order to make your question useful to future users, please do not simply post images of questions and instead type the questions.  This allows other users who have similar questions to you to use the search feature and find your question.  If you are having difficulty typing mathematics, consider visiting [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and learning how to use MathJax and $\LaTeX$ to type equations.  Finally, please include your thoughts and attempt on the question so we can help best.

Comment: @JMoravitz You made a lot of effort by writing the whole question (including the matrix) in $\LaTeX$. Respect.

Comment: @JMoravitz What is the idea behind to post an (nice) answer and then voting for "put on hold".

Comment: @calculus doing the two need not be mutually exclusive.  If more details were to have been given as to what the OP was having difficulty with, I could have provided a more targeted answer.  As it stands, I could only guess as to what the OP was having trouble with (probably in interpreting the "matrix representation" of the relation).  In voting to close, this should hopefully discourage the OP as well as others from simply posting questions without their thoughts.  Despite that, I still wanted to offer some help in the form of a hint (but not full answer) since it was a new user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Here is a directed graph representing the relation $\mathcal{R}$ with a directed edge from $x$ to $y$ iff $x\mathcal{R}y$.

[image]

Is it currently transitive?

> Look at $2$ and $5$.  You have $2\mathcal{R}4$ and you have $4\mathcal{R}5$ but...

What is the necessary edge(s) you need to make it transitive?

> By adding those necessary missing edges to the graph (equivalently to the relation) you form $\mathcal{R}^*$.  Remember, only add the edges you absolutely need to, don't add more than is necessary.

Is there a natural way to partition these elements so that in the image they are "grouped" how the edges appear?

Comment: I have tried for many hours to figure this out and still can't. Can you show me the right answer and how you got it because I haven't a clue. Thanks

Comment: @Tomi what in particular is giving you trouble?  Is it the definition of a relation?  Or perhaps the definition of transitivity?  What is the reason the current relation is not transitive?

Comment: @Tomi I'm currently showing you how I get to the right answer.  I get the answer by answering these questions: Is it currently transitive?  If not, what is one of the reasons it isn't transitive?  I change the relation by adding that edge (comparison) into the graph (relation).  I ask myself, is it still not transitive?  Why isn't it?  I then add that into my relation.  Repeat until there is no longer any reason why it isn't transitive.  For an extended hint, $2\mathcal{R} 4$ and $4\mathcal{R} 5$ but $2\not\!\!\mathcal{R}5$, so I add that edge in.  There is one other edge missing.  What is it?

Comment: 5R1 Is there anymore or is it fine with just that?

Comment: Also I finished the first part what do I do for the second part and how do I go about doing it? Write down the partition of the set A into equivalence classes induced by R∗.

Comment: @Tomi Yes, the only missing edges to make it a transitive relation is $2\mathcal{R}5$ and $5\mathcal{R}2$.  As for equivalence classes are concerned, notice that by adding those, our new relation happens to be *symmetric, reflexive, and transitive*.  In otherwords, it became an equivalence relation (lucky us).  Everything that is related in an equivalence relation can be written together as one "equivalence class."  Kind of how we can organize our grocery shelves with "ketchup" and "catsup" and "that red stuff noone likes" together as "the same thing."

Comment: @Tomi so, if we lazily replace saying $2\mathcal{R}5$ and use a more suggestive notation, $2\simeq 5$ and $2\simeq 4$ and $4\simeq 5$ etc... you have $1\simeq 1$ but nothing else., you have $3\simeq 3$ and nothing else, and you have $2\simeq 2, 2\simeq 4, 2\simeq 5, 4\simeq 2, 4\simeq 4, 4\simeq 5, 5\simeq 2, 5\simeq 4, 5\simeq 5$.  Its these "groups" (1), (3), (2,4,5) that are our "equivalence classes."